# pandas string replace any value of string after one rounded bracket "Only single Rounded bracket by python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i need to replace any after "(" in pandas dataframe by ""

```
Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama >> Tuscaloosa and 

df['RegionName']= df['RegionName'].str.replace(r"\s+\(.*\"","")
```

not work

Answer (score 1):

You can using `str.split`

```
s
Out[417]: 
0    Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama >> Tuscaloosa
0    Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama >> Tuscaloosa
0    Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama >> Tuscaloosa
0    Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama >> Tuscaloosa
dtype: object
s.str.split('(',1).str[0]
Out[418]: 
0    Tuscaloosa 
0    Tuscaloosa 
0    Tuscaloosa 
0    Tuscaloosa 
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract` (Using data from @Wen):

```
s.str.extract(r'([^(]+)')
```

```
0  Tuscaloosa
1  Tuscaloosa
2  Tuscaloosa
3  Tuscaloosa
```

Comment: Thnx alot it's work but i need to know the meaning of that and what is '([^(]+)' means